# How to configure Remote desktop on window server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, remote-access

I’m trying to connect over internet to my home workstation which has Windows Server 2008 R2 (Web Edition) installed from my PC at work (Windows 7 installed on it) via Remote Desktop. I configure the workstation to accept remote desktop and I can connect to it from my laptop if I’m within same Home LAN but I can’t establish the connection from my PC at work . My question is: Is possible to connect to my workstation over internet using remote desktop? Is there any step by step resource the setup this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Your home machine is likely behind a NAT firewall.  On your home router, you need to forward port 3389 to the machine that is running the Remote Desktop server.  Either that or look into setting up a VPN on your home network.